# JSON - Iteration over nested data

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file which is structured as follows :

```
{"products":[
    { "tvs":[
        {"samsung":[
            {"leds":[
                {
                 "product_id": "034567",
                 "product_name": "Samsung UA22F5100 22'' LED TV (Black)",
                 "model_no": "UA22F5100",
                 "brand": "Samsung",
                 "price": 399,
                 "screen_size": 22,
                 "screen_res": "1920 x 1080",
                 "usb": 1,
                 "hdmi": 1,
                 "screen_format": "LED",
                 "dimensions": "513.1 x 366.5 x 169.6",
                 "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                  
                },
                {
                 "product_id": "012468",
                 "product_name": "Samsung 23F4003 23'' LED TV (Black)",
                 "model_no": "23F4003",
                 "brand": "Samsung",
                 "price": 459,
                 "screen_size": 23,
                 "screen_res": "1366 x 768 pixels",
                 "usb": 1,
                 "hdmi": 1,
                 "screen_format": "LED",
                 "dimensions": "551.9 x 368.4 x 123.4",
                 "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                
                }
        ]},
        {"plasma":[
            {
             "product_id": "043291",
             "product_name": "Samsung 43F4100 43'' Plasma TV (Black)",
             "model_no": "43F4100",
             "brand": "Samsung",
             "price": 399,
             "screen_size": 43,
             "screen_res": "852 x 480",
             "usb": 2,
             "hdmi": 2,
             "screen_format": "Plasma",
             "dimensions": "1007.4 x 670.5 x 261.9",
             "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                 
           },
                etc...
```

I need to iterate over this after I retrieve the results from an ajax request. I would need to filter data for example, get only `leds'` objects. 
What is the best way to filter :
should I use `jquery's .each()`, or a `for in` loop ?

I am trying to iterate it using the .each() approach, but I am stuck on the part where I need to check if current object is `'leds'` or `'plasma'`.

On the other hand, if I use  `for (var x in obj)`, I get access to the name of the object through 'x' ..

So should I do it using `for in` loop? and how exactly would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that data contains your json

```
data.each(function(index, product) {
   product.each(function(index, tv) {
      tv.each(function(index, mark) {
         mark.each(function(index, type) {
            if (type=='leds') {
               // Do whatever you want ...
            }
         });
      });
   });
});
```

EDIT : Full with AJAX call

```
var obj = {};
obj.my_post_value = my_post_value;

var str = jQuery.param(obj);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'my_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: str,
    success: function (data) {
        // handle your successful stuff here
        data.each(function(index, product) {
           product.each(function(index, tv) {
              tv.each(function(index, mark) {
                 mark.each(function(index, type) {
                    if (type=='leds') {
                       // Do whatever you want ...
                    }
                 });
              });
           });
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // handle your unsuccessful stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: tahnks for your answer? Does this require me to parse them into a jquery object to use .each() ? I ve tried this but it doesn't really work.

Comment: it depends how do you get the data. AJAX ?

Comment: currently i'm using getJSON() method, but was thinking of using $.ajax with get request, as I need to control what happens on success, failure etc, so yes AJAX

Comment: I just edited my comment with a full ajax call in JQuery ;)
If you do not need to pass value, just delete lines before $.ajax ...
And in $.ajax delete line "data: str,"

Comment: after using this, I still can't get it to work.. I get this error on each iteration :
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each'`,

 which I think I fixed by converting to jquery object `$(product).each()` etc.. However, when I get to if `(type == 'leds')`, condition is never met.. which means something is missing or wrong

Comment: I dont think `type` can equate to `leds`.. as its comparing an object with string.. Correct me if im wrong :)
http://jsfiddle.net/XkXU4/3/

Comment: What is even more confusing is, that console.log(type) prints out all the json data.. ie. practically the data object

Comment: i have to admit that i'm confused x)

Comment: looking for something better ... i let you know if i find something :)

Comment: What do you mean? jquery's ajax datatype is set to json and the file is json! I wouldn't have a clue about it not being recognized..

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution from native javascript.

```
<html>
<script>
var jsonArray = {"products":[
    { "tvs":[
        {"samsung":[
            {"leds":[
                {
                 "product_id": "034567",
                 "product_name": "Samsung UA22F5100 22'' LED TV (Black)",
                 "model_no": "UA22F5100",
                 "brand": "Samsung",
                 "price": 399,
                 "screen_size": 22,
                 "screen_res": "1920 x 1080",
                 "usb": 1,
                 "hdmi": 1,
                 "screen_format": "LED",
                 "dimensions": "513.1 x 366.5 x 169.6",
                 "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                  
                },
                {
                 "product_id": "012468",
                 "product_name": "Samsung 23F4003 23'' LED TV (Black)",
                 "model_no": "23F4003",
                 "brand": "Samsung",
                 "price": 459,
                 "screen_size": 23,
                 "screen_res": "1366 x 768 pixels",
                 "usb": 1,
                 "hdmi": 1,
                 "screen_format": "LED",
                 "dimensions": "551.9 x 368.4 x 123.4",
                 "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                
                }
        ]},
        {"plasma":[
                {
                 "product_id": "043291",
                 "product_name": "Samsung 43F4100 43'' Plasma TV (Black)",
                 "model_no": "43F4100",
                 "brand": "Samsung",
                 "price": 399,
                 "screen_size": 43,
                 "screen_res": "852 x 480",
                 "usb": 2,
                 "hdmi": 2,
                 "screen_format": "Plasma",
                 "dimensions": "1007.4 x 670.5 x 261.9",
                 "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                 
               }
           ]
        }
        ]
}]
}]
};      

var brand = "samsung"; //I assume that you know, how to get this based on your design
var type = "leds"; //I assume that you know, how to get this based on your design

var typeArray = eval("jsonArray.products[0].tvs[0]."+brand+"[0]."+type);
if(typeArray .length){
    for(var i=0; i<typeArray .length; i++){
        var product_id = typeArray [i].product_id;
        alert(product_id);
    }
}
</script>
<body>                       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Asik, this works great an its so simple! However I d like something a little bit more dynamic.. for instance at some point, I would like to filter for samsung Leds, and in another point, i'd like to filter for Sony plasma's.. should I just use some javascipt to pass in the keys (ie samsung, sony or an other brand?) and then use string concatenation ?  Is that a good approach ?

Comment: @user2678538 If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: My comment in JQuery is a dynamic approach ;)

Comment: @Maxime I like how iterating over objects can be more flexible, if I could just get it to work

Comment: I'm trying to help but if you have some more code that'd be easier to give you more informations. Like your ajax call for example, maybe the name of your php page and if arguments are needed (post or get) precise them ;)

Comment: @user2678538, yes you can...I have updated my post..see that, it may be useful for you. Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks Asik.. I like how you use eval to be able to concatenate js dot notation